# Passing null in constructor argument

Tags: java

Scenario 1:
What if we pass `null` in constructor of a class and we have an overloaded constructor taking `Object` and second constructor having `String` as argument

Scenario 2 : 
What if we pass `null` in constructor of a class and we have an overloaded constructor taking `Integer` and second constructor having `String` as argument and third constructor has `Object` as argument

Scenario 3 : 
What if we pass `null` in constructor of a class and we have overloaded constructor taking `Exception` and second constructor having `ArithmeticException` as argument and third constructor has `Object` as argument

Answer to case 1 `String`

Answer to case 2 Compiler error , Ambiguous methods

Answer to case 3 `ArithmeticException`

Please explain me the logic behind the above answers

Comment: You're basically retyping the question of your previous post, without the code. And they're pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: How it is self explanatory ? There is nothing mention like that in Oracle docs

Comment: I don't think the answer to scenario 1 is String. Actually it's ambiguous as String and Integer are in the same "level" in the object hierarchy.

Comment: I ran the code and answers written in the site are correct

Comment: Follow the link I included. I googled it and found it. Try a little harder next time.

Comment: @Noopur Scenario 1 in action for the proof... http://ideone.com/LLqsXo

Comment: @ZouZou I think he mistyped the first scenario somehow. The blog he linked last time has `String` and `Object`

Comment: my mind is not working as it is already 4am , but i will check this post , thanks for the link Method overloading for null  , good night

Comment: Noopur, if you go to the second page of the questions that you linked to in your earlier question, there's a link down the bottom to a page that gives full explanations of all the answers. Please don't ask the SO community to retype information that you already have.

Answer (score -1):

remeber it works in this way.

first searches for any ambuguity method if so compile time error.

example define `A(String) and A(Integer) then calling A(null)` becomes ambiguity.

so calling time compile time error.

if no ambiguity,then searches for more specific type first then least specific type.

ie if `class A extends B`

then B will be given first priority and then A is given importance.

so in your scenarios

case 1:

one int and one String method so no ambiguity and string one is called. however if one is integer instead of int then calling with null gives error.

case 2:ambiguity because calling method wit null can not be choosen between Integer and String as both are not hierarchical classes.

case 3: no ambiguity because all are hierarchical classes and most specific one is Arithmetic exception class so that one is choosen.

`Object->Exception->ArithmeticExcepton` so Arithmetic exception is choosen